# Get response from a s3 triggered lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function that gets triggered when a file is uploaded to s3. This lambda generates a json, and `put` that json to `s3`. I want to fetch the contents of this json in the frontend (react js), after it is uploaded to s3.

However, I don't know how to find out when the json file has been uploaded to s3 by the function. I can probably continuously poll the s3, and check if the file exists.

Does there exist any better way to know if the function is done executing?

Comment: Hey @jsdbt. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **AWS Simple Notification Service** (SNS), where you can create a **topic** attached to the S3 bucket. You then can subscribe to that topic to receive messages as soon as a new item is uploaded.

[For more information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

Comment: Thanks. I read about SNS. While it can email me the json data, I want the browser/reactjs to know that the transcription has been completed - so that I can display the transcript in browser. Couldnt figure out if one can send the data back to browser and how ..